# How to unit test whether a test is loaded or not in Angular2 Jasmine test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a module with some services loaded to the constructor

```
export class AppModule {
    constructor(
                private oauth: OAuthService, //HOW TO TEST THIS WHETHER ITS LOADED OR NOT?
                private translate: TranslateService
    ){

        let browserLang = navigator.language;
        
        if(browserLang.length == 2) {
            browserLang = browserLang == 'en' ? 'en-US' : browserLang;
            browserLang = browserLang == 'de' ? 'de-AT' : browserLang;
        }
        translate.use(browserLang || 'en-US');
    }
}
```

How do I unit test to check whether instances ofOAuthService and TranslateService are getting loaded into AppModule using Angular2 Jasmine?

Comment: What have you got as your test setup right now? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

One way to test if an NgModule provides a service is to create a TestComponent that injects your service via constructor, and then use `TestBed.configureTestingModule` to make a test module that imports your module and declares the TestComponent.  If your module specifies the OAuthService under `providers` then you should receive the service in your TestComponent.

Another thing to note: this isn't the recommended way to declare and use a module in angular2.  Normally you would use the @NgModule decorator to define what your module imports, exports, provides, and declares.  Check out the [official docs on NgModule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) for some examples.